# Ubuntu 12.04 with Subversion Edge and SLES 11 with Subversion Edge

Tags: ubuntu, svn, users, sles, migration

I have a server (SLES 11) witch Subversion Edge. On this svn, i have repository and users. I have to migrate this svn on a Ubuntu server 12.04. I have installed Subversion Edge on this server. Now I would like to migrate the users on this servers.

Can you help me ? How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0):

Move your repositories to the new machine and see [SVN Edge documentation](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/action/connectexistingrepository.html).